# Format ReceivedTime of Outlook Message in Powershell

Tags: powershell, outlook

I am working currently to get the receivedTime of a message in outlook and save it to a variable. Currently I am using the following code:

```
$Folder.Items | foreach{
    $date = $_.ReceivedTime
    $date
}
```

The result of this code gives me output as followed:

Tuesday, October 21, 2014 8:00:36 AM

I am trying to format this as a numeric date such as 10212014 or 10_21_2014.

How can I change this format to match one of those cases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use this;

`$date = $_.ReceivedTime.ToString("MMddyyyy")`

Some more useful info [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730960.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If the $_.ReceivedTime property isn't already a DateTime type, you can force that and then use the formatting suggestion from Christopher by using:

```
[DateTime]$date  = $_.ReceivedTime
$date.Tostring("MMddyyyy")
```

If you want underscores just put them in like:

```
$date.Tostring("MM_dd_yyyy")
```

Another useful resource formatting dates can be found [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692801.aspx)